# Modify javafx Label properites while being displayed

Tags: java, javafx

I dynamically add Labels to an empty HBox `displayBox` to represent vertical bars of width 60.0 and random height using `genNewArray()` linked to a button. These bars are passed by the `MakeBar` class and stored in the static array `MakeBar[] valueArray;`. Aiming to later sort these bars by height I first ran a test that makes all the same height using `startVisual()` linked to `vizButton`.

The problem is that the change is shown only after the entire loop is complete. I need the modifications to be shown while the loop is running i.e. as it changes.

Controller Class:

```
public class SortContr implements Initializable {

    static MakeBar[] valueArray;

    private static Random random = new Random();

    @FXML
    private Label newRandArray;

    @FXML
    private Slider barNumSlider;

    @FXML
    private Button vizButton;

    @FXML
    private HBox displayBox;


    @FXML
    void genNewArray(MouseEvent event) {

        displayBox.getChildren().clear();
        int arrsize = (int) barNumSlider.getValue();
        valueArray = new MakeBar[arrsize];

        for (int i=0;i<arrsize;i++) {
            valueArray[i] = new MakeBar(random.nextInt(500));
            displayBox.getChildren().add(valueArray[i].getBar());
        }
        vizButton.setDisable(false);
    }


    @FXML
    void startVisual(ActionEvent event) throws InterruptedException {

        /*for (Node n:displayBox.getChildren()) {
            ((Label) n).setPrefHeight(60);
            n.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #8bff3a;");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }*/

        for (int i=0;i<valueArray.length;i++) {
            valueArray[i].modifyHeight(100);
            //System.out.println(i);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

        vizButton.setDisable(true);
    }
}
```

Clicking Visualize ! :
[image: During loop]

After entire process is finished.
[image: After loops executed]

MakeBar:

```
public class MakeBar {

    @FXML
    private Label bar;

    MakeBar(int ht) {
        this.bar = new Label();
        this.bar.setPrefWidth(60.0);
        this.bar.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #5dade2;");
        this.bar.setPrefHeight(ht);
    }

    Label getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    void modifyHeight(double newHeight) {
        this.bar.setPrefHeight(newHeight);
    }
}
```

I need it to show each bar changing at a time.

I know i could clear and load the widgets after each iteration but that seems inefficient. The main problem lies in `startVisual()` . I'm not too well versed in JavaFx.

I use IntellijIdea and SceneBuilder.

Comment: If you sleep on the FX Application Thread, you prevent the UI from being rendered. See (among many other examples) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62200942/about-pausetransition-in-javafx for the correct approach.

Comment: This was the post I was trying to find: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61988534/javafx-rectangle-doesnt-update